# Не запускается новая DomU - CentOS 7. HVM

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, xen

```
[root@SystemManager xen]# cat Centos7.hvm 
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader"
builder='hvm'
name = "Centos7"
memory = "1024"
disk = ['phy:/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Asterisk,hda,w', 'file:/mnt/usb_HHD/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1503-01.iso,hdb:cdrom,w']
vif = ['type=ioemu,bridge=avpublic']
device_model = "/usr/lib64/xen/bin/qemu-dm"
boot="d"
vnc=1
vcpus=1
serial = "pty"
on_shutdown = "destroy"
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = "preserve"
[root@SystemManager xen]#
```

Установка проходит замечательно, никаких ошибок.

```
[root@SystemManager admin]# cat /etc/xen/Centos7.hvm 
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader"
builder='hvm'
name = "Centos7"
memory = "1024"
disk = ['phy:/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Asterisk,hda,w']
vif = ['type=ioemu,bridge=avpublic']
device_model = "/usr/lib64/xen/bin/qemu-dm"
boot="c"
vnc=1
vcpus=1
serial = "pty"
on_shutdown = "destroy"
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = "preserve"
[root@SystemManager admin]#
```

При запуске происходит crash, и если в конфиге стоит параметр on_crash = «preserve», то состояние сохраняется и имеется возможность узнать, что оно нам поведало перед смертью, иначе просто вырубает. И вот что перед крашем выводится: [Crash](http://i5.imageban.ru/out/2015/10/06/95ce84046c47a5da51b76470059de3da.jpeg). Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Он там что-то про рут файл систем ругается. И в начале скрина и в конце. Локальные права на файл винта нормальные? Руками подмонтировать и сделать ls можно? В dmesg есть матюки по этому поводу?

Comment: /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Asterisk,hda,w. А точно hda? IDE в виде эмуляции вроде как давно умер. Всё через sata. Если на sda поменять не поможет?

Comment: Уже пробовал sda, до того как сюда написал.

Comment: А что по поводу остальных вопросов?

Comment: По поводу остальных вопросов, в каком dmesg, в хостовой или виртуальной? Если в витруальной то я не могу посмотреть, а чем мне может dmesg хостовой машины? Второе, локальные права на файл винта: руками примонтировать можно, уже сто раз это делал а где файл винта найти? Это что за файл

Comment: "чем мне может dmesg хостовой машины."

Ну, туда часто что-нить попадает про поломки или конфликты.

"где файл винта найти?"

Вот тут я пасс. Я просто по опыту виртуалбокса говорю, что может какая проблема быть в файлах на хосте. Просто предположения вслепую.